# Copy/Paste is working sporadically in Firefox Developer Edition

Tags: firefox-developer-edition

I am on a Mac Book Pro version 10.13.4.  I just recently started using the developer version.  I can not copy something from the browser to other applications on my system.  Has anyone else had this issue?  I also have a new computer, so I can't pin point where the issue is.  Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: What do you mean by "copy something"?

Comment: Highlighting text in address bar, or within text and using Command C.  Then trying to paste it into text edit or dreamweaver OR vice versa. Copy something from Text edit and paste into address bar, or a backend of a wordpress site.

Comment: Gotcha!  Very interesting.  Thanks for clarifying.  I'm not sure if this is a programming question - maybe it makes more sense elsewhere, like on SuperUser?